# SecKey API returned: -25304 libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

Since 10.12 Sierra major update, I can't compile one of my iOS projects on ***only on device***. But very weird, it's work on simulator.
I tried to remove and resetup my dev account in Xcode, hard reboot, remove and resetup all certificates in keychain, etc.
XCode 8.0. I tried also on 8.1 beta too, same.

The error :

> SecKey API returned: -25304, (null)/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-epkppprfmidyatftsvnxgjqsawit/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/****.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
>   error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
>       /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' 'C47B52FDE2CABFC81D33BED8937984AF8BC6DC33' '--verbose' '/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-epkppprfmidyatftsvnxgjqsawit/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/***.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'

Comment: What are the versions of your iOS on simulator/real device?

Comment: 10.0 on simulator, 10.0.2 on device.

Comment: Would you post an exact code that is causing the error messages? Or what user's action?

Comment: This error happens during compilation for device, before app launching.

Hopefully, It's now working good on other mac (personal) with same OS X, same Xcode version, same iOS device, same dev account, etc. But I really ned to get this working ok on my professional Mac.

Comment: Removed information, that is not related to the question.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Jenkins, any luck solving it?

Comment: Any luck solving this? I'm getting a similar error but the API returns: -25308.

Comment: I am also getting same error when building with Jenkins "SecKey API returned: -25308 ....." Did you guys get any solution?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue,

Unlock your keychain by adding this line to your projects configuration (Build>Execute shell)

> #unlock the keychain
>   security unlock-keychain -p "myPrettyPassword" $HOME/Library/Keychains/MyPrettyKeychain.keychain

Comment: I was getting below error but it has solved by shell command.  API returned: -25308

Comment: I am using fastlane to build from a jenkins job and was getting this error. Executing the above command in the terminal one time worked. I omitted the -p and manually typed in my password the first prompt.